# How to show data in Extjs grid.panel

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

Is this the correct way to initialize my view?
I have this code:

```
Ext.define('AS.view.View', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.view',
    store: 'Store',

    initComponent: function () {}
});
```

The store is configured on the grid, shouldn't I see data?. Can someone help me?

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should put `this.callParent(arguments);` in the initComponent method
2. You can either autoload the store or call load() on the store when your view renders.

Either:

```
//store config
autoLoad: true
```

or

```
//view config
listeners: {
   render: function(){
       this.store.load();
   }
}
```

you also need to configure columns.
See full working example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/array-grid.html