# Extjs - getting 'TypeError: name is undefined' when add grid panel with store data in view

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, store

I am trying to simply load a grid panel with data from a store in my view, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: name is undefined
Line: if (name === from || name.substring(0, from.length) === from) {
```

I have experimented with how I am initializing the panel, here is what I have currently:

```
Ext.define('BP.view.induction.RightPage', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias : 'widget.rightpage',

title: "Right Page",    

items: [
    {
        title: 'Tasks',
        html: '',
        cId: 'tasksTab',
        initComponent: function() {
            this.add( [{
                store: 'Tasks',
                xtype: 'taskgrid',
                hideHeaders: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        text     : 'Task ID',
                        flex     : 0,
                        sortable : false,
                        hidden   : true,
                        dataIndex: 'id'
                    }, 
                    {
                        text     : 'Task',
                        flex     : 1,
                        sortable : false,
                        dataIndex: 'name'
                    },

                ]
            }]);

            this.callParent();
        } 
    },{
        title: 'Content',
        html: '',
        cId: 'contentTab'
    }
]
});
```

Originally I didn't have the initComponent function, instead building items immediately - but this produced the same error.

[Edit] As requested, here is the store definition:

```
Ext.define('BP.store.Tasks', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: 'BP.model.Task',
model: 'BP.model.Task',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : '/resources/data/tasks.php',
    reader: {
        type:'json',
        root:'tasks'
    }
},
autoLoad: true
});
```

The full data is unwieldy, but here is a sample (json formatted):

```
{"success":true,
"tasks":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Cleaning Products","content":"Lorem ipsum...","resource_type":"text","resource_url":"","category_id":1},
    {"id":2,"name":"Preservatives","content":"Lorem ipsum...","resource_type":"text","resource_url":"","category_id":1}]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the store configuration when it goes to try and get the name field for one of the records.  Can you post the store definition/initialization as well as the data that it loads?

Comment: That message is usually when it can't find one of the classes you're trying to load using strings, like "Tasks", try changing that to "BP.store.Tasks", if that doesn't work, you need to debug your script and see the stack and check out what is the class it's trying to create and having problems doing so

Answer (score 5):

initComponent goes into class definition. in your code sample you are creating a tab panel with a generic Tasks panel to whcih you are trying to set an initComponent method.
If you need that initComponent method you then need to create a separate class definition for your Tasks grid.  You can't inline it.

In addition, what you are doing is overnesting panels. If you add a gridpanel to a tabpanel it automatically becomes one of the Tabs. You don't need to wrap a grid into another panel.

On debugging: make sure to use a debug version of the ExtJS lib (or the dev version). Use FF or Chrome to debug (whichever you like more). If you use FF, do get firebug addon called Illuminations for Developers - it helps tremendously with layout issues and to understand containerships and nesting issues. It also lets you see records in your store after they are loaded from server.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I don't need the initComponent, more that I tried it when my original approach didn't work. Excellent heads up on Illuminations too - this looks very useful! :)

Comment: Do you perhaps have any ideas why my grid isn't getting populated with the store data - please see the comments from sra's answer. Thanks :)

Comment: It's difficult to tell from what you have so far. Can you create a new question and add just the grid definition and how you  are loading the store etc.

Comment: Not had chance to look at this again yet, but will create a new question if I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to dbrin's answer I am pretty sure that you didn't defined a widget called *taskgrid* which would cause your error.

Anyway, remove the `initComponent()` method and the `add()` method. In your case you can directly assign all to `items:[]` (subnote 2) that would result in the same and is the proper way of doing it. The `add()` method get called on instances that are already created (this may cause the error, too. See subnote 1). Also spare empty `html` properties.

**Subnotes**

1. If you ever have the need for calling a method like add within a class defintions `initComponent()` method you need to enshure that you called `callParent(arguments);` first!
2. Code example

```
Ext.define('BP.view.induction.RightPage', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias : 'widget.rightpage',

title: "Right Page",    

items: [
    {
        store: 'Tasks',
        title: 'Tasks',
        xtype: 'taskgrid',
        cId: 'tasksTab',
        hideHeaders: true,
        columns: [
            {
                text     : 'Task ID',
                sortable : false,
                hidden   : true,
                dataIndex: 'id'
            }, 
            {
                text     : 'Task',
                flex     : 1,
                sortable : false,
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }
        ]
    },{
        title: 'Content',
        cId: 'contentTab'
    }
]
});
```

**Edit**

A xtype is a defined alias. Currently there are four; [widget](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.enums.Widget), [feature](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.enums.Feature), [layout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.enums.Layout), [plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.enums.Plugin).  In case of components you use the widget type. You can define your own by using `alias: 'widget.yourname'` and voilá you have your own xtype. You can refer to it using `xtype: 'yourname'`
Why the grid not renders is hard to tell. It may depend on definitions within your extension or on the container where you render it into.

Comment: Thanks, I continue to be confused between xtype and alias - I changed the above from xtype to alias and this fixed the error. I shall try to remember the difference in future! So, now my code produces no errors but at the same time the grid is not actually rendering in the tab? Thanks to Illumination, I can see that the store is loaded and contains the expected data - not sure why its not displaying however?

Comment: @BrynJ Edit done. And be aware that the Illumination plugin can be tricky. I droped it after a short test phase. But the it may have improved since then.

Comment: Thanks. I tried suggestion from dbrin here for same issue of data not rendering in grid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477274/how-to-show-data-in-extjs-grid-panel - following the answer, I am told that this.store.load() is undefined. Anyhow, I will try workaround this issue. Can I ask what issues Illumination posed - so I know what to look out for?

Comment: @BrynJ It produced randomly errors within the console that seems to come from the application code. You can simply check within the console if your store exist under the right name calling `Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('Tasks')` An empty store will not stop a grid from rendering!

Comment: I entered that command into the console and can confirm that the store definitely exists. All the more strange?!

Comment: @BrynJ If you don't have a really good reason for extending the grid class then test it like `store: 'Tasks',title: 'Tasks',xtype: 'grid',cId: 'tasksTab', hideHeaders: false, activeTab: 0, ....` and see what happends. Please note that no tab is set active without the activeTab config!

Comment: Just to say, not had chance to do this yet but appreciate the suggestion. Will report back when I have.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using the architect to build my project.  It turned out to be a syntax error in the proxy configuration.  Try modifying yours to look like this.  It worked for me. 
Rather than just a URL, specify an api, with a read parameter.

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: '/resources/data/tasks.php'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'tasks'
    }
}
```

Comment: I faced with the same TypeError of the author in ExtJs 4.2.1 on the stage when controller loads model and store. Your solution helped me when I rewrite store proxy configuration in detailed way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case with the exact error, i solved it by added a constructor:

```
constructor: function(config) {
      this.initConfig(config);
      return this;
}
```

In my case i needed the initComponent, so final code will be something like:

```
Ext.define('SomeNewField', {
 extend: 'Ext.Something',
 alias: 'widget.SomeNewField',

initComponent: function(config) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

constructor:function(config) {
      this.initConfig(config);
      return this;
 }
```